# Android : droidar setting up POIs and show details on click

Tags: android, augmented-reality

In my app i want to use augmented reality to show some predefined POIs . When user click on the POI object, i want to show more detail about that store / object.

As i was looking for free AR framework , i came across Droidar. I saw its wiki and samples and have got an idea about structure. I understood how to add POIs. I need help on making them as clickable and adding an event on click.

Please share any tutorials if you know.

Also what is the link for droidar documentations.

Comment: Can you help me out in implementing DroidAR?

Answer (score 0):

You could always attach a setOnClickCommand to your POI

```
poiObj.gObj.setOnClickCommand(new POIDisplayCommand(getActivity(), poiObj));
```

In the above case I have a POI object poiObj which has a GeoObj member gObj. By using the setOnClickCommand I have called a POIDisplayCommand which loads a new Activity which displays the details about the clicked POI. The POIDispplayCommand is a class that extends the commands.Command

If you need more on the above method you could always check the StaticDemoSetup.java in de.rwth.setups package of the DroidAR library in your IDE.